# Is there a way to record myself while I use an application other than the camera?

Tags: camera, video-recording

I would like to record myself playing music. At first, I could easily open the Android Camera app and record. However, I need that the PDF document containing the sheet music be open on my smartphone so that I can see what notes to play.

If I open the Android Camera app, start recording and go to another app, the Camera will cancel the record.

Comment: That seems to be a limitation of your camera app. Google Play Store contains other camera apps that claim to be able to record videos while in background. https://play.google.com/store/search?q=video%20record%20background&c=apps

Comment: In this particular case you are much likely to benefit from taking a print out and use that instead of following a PDF.